# JPA implementation that fully support with PostgreSQL data types?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, nosql, postgresql-9.2

Is there any JPA implementation that supports PostgreSQL hstore, geolocation and array data types ?

Comment: Most of them are extensible; I doubt any have support out of the box. I had enough trouble with even simpler types like `json` and `xml` in EclipseLink and Hibernate.

Comment: eclipselink 2.4 currently support @Array but neither with hstore or geolocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update :**

This time i have made a few converters for geo point and array (limitied to array string and long) datatype, please check https://github.com/brain64bit/myeclipselink_converter

Answer (score 2):

DataNucleus has a [spatial plugin that includes Postgresql spatial types](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/datastores/rdbms_spatial_types.html) (but it goes way beyond it). It doesn't explicitly do Postgresql array types but it is readily extensible, so you could write your own plugin for **any** missing type.

Answer (score 1):

You have got [Hibernate spatial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) which is a generic extension to Hibernate for handling geographic data

Comment: the project is outdated, i've no luck with this

Comment: @kav1nsky I think you have missed tutorials and other things about it. It is very nice enhancement for Hibernate for PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I am currently working with this. And it is working very perfectly.

Comment: I do not know what is outdated too. This project is still active : "We are currently working on migrating Hibernate Spatial to a module of the Hibernate ORM project. The move will be complete by the time of the Hibernate 5 release. The Hibernate Spatial Release 4 will be therefore be the last release that is made independently of Hibernate." That is not an easy task to migrate for full jdbc/sql to JPA and I do not think you will find a better lib for your needs.